# Convert rownum() from db2 to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, rownum

Good day,

I would like to change some program code (mostly on SQL code) because the database already change from DB2 to Oracle.

Here is 1 example that I successful changed but I am not really understand about it, and I cant find it from google.

The following is the original SQL Query code (using DB2) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT T0.CREATEDBY AS C1, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY T0.GROUPNAME) AS rownum 
FROM IBSADMIN.CCGROUP T0 
WHERE T0.GROUPID != 0001 AND T0.GROUPID != 001 AND T0.CHANNEL = 'CC') AS tname
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Here is the SQL Query code after edit by me (successfully get data from Oracle) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT T0.CREATEDBY AS C1, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY T0.GROUPNAME) AS rownum1 
FROM IBSADMIN.CCGROUP T0 
WHERE T0.GROUPID != 0001 AND T0.GROUPID != 001 AND T0.CHANNEL = 'CC') tname
WHERE rownum1 BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

As I analyze, I get error if I didnt change the `rownum` to `rownum1`, error is `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` .Thus I change it to `rownum1`, I think the `rownum` should be a keyword in DB2, is there any keyword like this for Oracle also?

In the line 4 last part, from DB2 code, it end with `As tname`. If I put the same things in Oracle code, I get error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` . Thus I erase the `As` . I not so understand how is the `As tname` means, As the SQL query in the bracket:

```
(SELECT T0.CREATEDBY AS C1, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY T0.GROUPNAME) AS rownum1 
    FROM IBSADMIN.CCGROUP T0 
    WHERE T0.GROUPID != 0001 AND T0.GROUPID != 001 AND T0.CHANNEL = 'CC')
```

It return me 2 columns, thus I am not understand how is the `As tname` interate with the 2 column.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `rownum` is a reserved word in Oracle-- in Oracle, `rownum` is a pseudocolumn that you can reference to get the row number (before ordering) of a result set.  That's why you need to change the alias when you convert to Oracle.  I would prefer something that was more obviously different from `rownum`-- `rn` or `rnk` are good options.
2. `tname` is an alias for the inline view in your query.  In Oracle, you cannot use the `AS` keyword to assign a table alias (you can optionally use it when defining a column alias which is why `AS rownum1` is valid but you could also get rid of the `AS` entirely).  In this case, the `tname` alias is never used so in Oracle you could omit it.  I know in some databases (SQL Server) aliases for inline views are required-- I'm not sure whether DB2 requires the table alias.

It sounds like you modified the query correctly (though I quibble with the alias you chose instead of `rownum`).

Comment: Hi Justin. Thanks for your explanation In your first paragraph. Do you means that I change the `rownum` to `rownum1` is not so suitable, and you suggest change it to more different word like `rn` or `rnk`. Do you means this? or other things?

Comment: @PanadolChong - Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Is it the DB2 SQL query in my question accidently use the `rownum` which `rownum` actually is a keyword in `Oracle` ? There is nothing wrong if I use `rownumber` instead of `rownum` in DB2 right? or `rownum` is actually also a keyword in DB2?

Comment: @PanadolChong - 'rownumber` is not a keyword in DB2.  So you could use `rownumber` or `rn` or `rnk` as your alias in both databases and have your query be reasonably readable.

Answer (score 0):

May be nobody is still interested in this, but I found this solution here:

http://www.sqlines.com/db2-to-oracle/fetch_first_rows_only

use  `FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY`, something like:

```
select * from a_table  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

will give you only the first line of the table, I've used this and it worked just as I expected.